# How to set the background color of selected row in tableview which is child tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which is inside the a tableview cell.

After click the "JAVA" inside "test1", I click the "About" Row which don't have the tableview inside:

[image]

But you can see that, the "About" and "JAVA" have the background colour at the same time. This is the automatic feature of tableview in iOS, I don't know how to code to prevent this happen. What I want is that when I click the "Java" inside "test1", the background color of "About" would disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to keep track of which cell was selected if you only want one cell selected at a time from both table views.

The best way to do that is to create a delegate for the nested tableview.  So when that cell is selected it can call back to the parent tableview and let it know to unselect anything that was selected.  The main class will need to keep track of the index that was selected as if another one is chosen then it can reach into the cell with selected cell and deselect that.

A little tricky, are you sure you can't get the same results from just using one tableview and multiple sections?

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I get this logic to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it helps you

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greyColor()
}
```

To deselect the selected row use this code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cellToDeSelect:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cellToDeSelect.contentView.backgroundColor = colorForCellUnselected
}
```